# Limit of the product is infinity

Tags: limits, generating-functions

How can we proof it?
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{p_i\leqslant{n}}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p_i}} = \infty$
Thanks

Comment: The $p_i$ are primes?, and the fraction needs $p_i$ not $p$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, $p_i$ are primes.

Comment: take natural logs of the left hand side and use $\log(1-x) \sim x$ and $\sum_{p_i} \frac{1}{p_i}$ diverges?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma why $\sum_{p_i}\frac{1}{p_i}}$ diverges?

Comment: See [this proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes) which uses your infinite product (so it goes the other way).

Comment: $p_i\over{p_i-1}$ is always greater than 1 multiplying anything greater than 1 infinitely many times will give an infinite result is my first thought.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: Wrong. Note that's equivalent to saying that "summing anything greater than $0$ infinitely many times will give an infinite result", once you consider the logarithm of an infinite product.

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is prime then that product is the Euler product formula for the Riemann zeta function.

$\displaystyle \prod_{p \hspace{1 mm}prime} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}=\zeta(s)$. For $s=1$ you get the harmonic series which is divergent so your product is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequence of [the Euler product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Euler_product_formula) and the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges.